# How to properly install OpenGL in VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, opengl, installation

I am trying install OpenGL on VS2010.

I use [this tutorial](http://arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Building%20the%20Tutorials.html).

And I get the following error:

```
Unable to start program 'C:\Users\s151310\Tutorial 0.3.8\frameworkD.lib'.
The specified file is an unrecognized or unsupported binary format
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Actually don't have to install anything at all to start OpenGL development with Visual Studio. As long as you limit yourself to OpenGL-1.1 and core Win32 APIs everything is already in place for you.

However to get modern OpenGL features one must use the so called *extension mechanism* to load pointers to functions of newer versions – a tedious and uninteresting process. Hence extension loader wrappers have been developed.

Also creating a window and setting up a matching OpenGL context is laborous as well. So you want to use some framework for that two.

Extension loader wrappers and frameworks are 3rd party libraries that need to be installed separately.

> Unable to start program 'C:\Users\s151310\Tutorial 0.3.8\frameworkD.lib

Why are you trying to execute a library file? This is the framework library that's supposed to be linked into your executables. So this raises the question: How did you setup your project, specifically which build options did you configure. Without that I can't give better advice.